# Changing all subreports linked in reports at once

Tags: crystal-reports

I have around 150+ reports that have a subreport as a footer. In this subreport is some basic company information.

I have to add some more information in the footer.

Is there a way to do this fast? Or do I have to manually edit every report to display this new column?

As far as I can tell when you include a subreport in a report this subreport is saved IN the report that you included it in, right?

So changing the footer file won't instantly update all the reports that have the footer included as a subreport?

Is there a faster wya to do this than to manually edit every single report that has the footer as a subreport?